# Select the latest record based on certain criteria in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with real-time scanning data from our employees. As you can see, each boxes can be scanned multiple times, even employees can scan the boxes multiple time for one status.

I am trying to pull the latest record for each box, but the status for the latest record should be "Refused"

From the picture, as you can see, although Carton 1234 has a record with status "Refused", but this record is not the last one, so I don’t need this. And the carton 1235 is what I need.

I don’t want to use a window function to rank each record in the table first, because I have a lot of rows in the table, and I think it will be time consuming.

So is there any better way to achieve my goal?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use PL/SQL rather than plain SQL?

Comment: "I don’t want to use a window function (...), because (...) I think it will be time consuming." An SQL approach is likely very less time consuming than firing up any procedural stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you don't really need a PL/SQL solution. Here is SQL only:

This is a solution without window functions:

```
select *
from mytable
where (carton_id, scantime) in
(
  select carton_id, max(scantime)
  from mytable
  group by carton_id
  having max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by scantime) = 'Refused'
);
```

But I don't think that this is superior to using a window function. So you can just as well try

```
select *
from
(
  select mytable.*, max(scantime) over (partition by carton_id) as max_scantime
  from mytable
  group by carton_id
)
where scantime = max_scantime and status = 'Refused';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'Refused' and
      t.scantime = (select max(t2.scantime) from t t2 where t2.carton_id = t.carton_id);
```